# Kickstarting while loop in javascript(while using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am currently learning javascript and trying to make a simple game with it,when i click ENTER button on my keyboard it should start the game,as you see game_mode would be 1,then while loop should start printing "working",for me to know that it's looping but somewhy,when game_mode becomes 1 the loop doesnt start,why is this happening?I am using this loop in

```
$(document).ready(function())
```

Because of jquery.

P.S i know that it would loop forever,i just need to see it loop.Thank you for your time

```js
  while(game_mode===1)
    {
     
      alert("working");
    }
    $(document).keydown(function(event){ //For moving keys
      if(game_mode===1)
      {
        moveKeys();
      }
      if(event.which===13)          //IF ENTER IS PRESSED
      {
        if(game_mode===0)
        {
          game_mode+=1;
          $("#phase_mode").text("Started");
        }else if(game_mode==1)
        {
          $("#phase_mode").text("Paused");
          game_mode+=1;
        }else
        {
            $("#phase_mode").text("Started");
            game_mode-=1;
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the while loop inside the `if(game_mode===0)` condition if you want it to alert "working" message, But really you should not do that, because you will create an infinite loop that will crash your app/browser.

Comment: Then i can not utilize my other keydown checks and that way close the loop,should i just use recursion with this?

Comment: No you cant use anything when the loop is turning.

Comment: What you want to acheive here?

Comment: well if loop is running,that means that game is happening and when i click enter i would like to stop it just like i started it when i clicked enter

Comment: The problem is this is synchronous code, and JavaScript, a single threaded language, won't be able to detect keystrokes at all because the loop will be running. Instead, maybe attach call back functions to the event listeners.

Comment: The is happening also without the loop, you can just print working word in some span and change it when you click enter, i cant see any utility of loop here.